# executing batch files sequentially

Tags: vbscript

```
dim shell,x,y  
x="D:\d"  
y="c.bat " & x  
set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")  
shell.run y  
shell.run "a.bat"  

set shell=nothing
```

When I run this script it runs both batch files simultaneously. What I need is that it run the first batch file(c.bat) and after it is completely executed, it should execute the other batch file(a.bat).
What I need works fine if I make another batch file and use:

```
call c.bat  
call a.bat
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
shell.run y, 1, true
shell.run "a.bat", 1, true
```

for details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(VS.85).aspx

Comment: The last parameter (true) means to wait for the program to finish before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in VBScript, but you can create another batch file seq.bat that simply has the following and call it with 'seq.bat d:\d'

```
@echo off
call c.bat %1
call a.bat 1
```