# Run Script if press the close(x) button in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to run a script if i press the close(x) button in the batch file. Suppose batch file is running, if i press the close(x) button i want to run some script before closing the batch file incomplete run.

Comment: You can't (or, at least, not without hosting the batch file inside of a program) - please update your question with what you are attempting to achieve and there might be a better approach we can suggest.

Comment: I want to run a label(some set of commands) before closing the batch file when the batch file running is in progress by press close(x) button.

Comment: Can i avoid closing the batch file when i press the close(x) button while batch file is running.

Answer (score 1):

Use `start` from a different batch file and add the /WAIT argument.

As such:

```
@echo off
start %cd%/yourbatchfilehere.bat /WAIT
REM additional post-close code here.
```

[Additional info here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntstart.php)

This is, as far as I can see, the only appropriate way to get even close to solving your problem using only the system you asked us to use. Since windows' batch implementation provides no way to detect when a batch window is closing and stop it.

Comment: This code will run your other batch file _in a new window._ When that _other_ window closes, anything after `REM additional post-close code here` will be run.

Comment: I have a main.bat file in which i main using mk123456 batch file for compiling my codes. Previously i used "CALL mk123456" to execute the batch file. Now i am using START CALL mk123456 /WAIT but mk123456 batch file itself is not executing...even i tried with START mk123456 /WAIT but no use..

Comment: Use START %cd%/mk123456.bat /WAIT

Comment: I have used "START /WAIT mk123456" and it works...but this batch file is not closing automatically after executing, This is creating a new problem.

Comment: That's the trade off, if you want this functionality, you will need both batch windows.

Comment: @ChandraSekharK You need to add `exit` at the end of your "mk123456.bat" batch file - or it will not exit the cmd window.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into something like [this](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-bat-files-invisibly-without-displaying-command-prompt/). To avoid a user closing the window - just don't show them the window.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "mk123456.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following vbs script, which will run two files ('Hidden.bat' and 'Visible.bat') so that when 'Visible' is closed, 'Hidden' will run without being shown. This is based on unclemeat's answer and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2590398/4149474).

```
set WshShell=createobject("wscript.shell") 
WshShell.run "Visible.bat", 1, true
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "Hidden.bat" & Chr(34), 0
```

However I don't know how to pass arguments (especially multi-word ones) to the batch script.